# Realm-cocoa: How to add notification inside other notification block

Tags: ios, objective-c, realm

In my app, I have registered a notification block that itself has to register an other notifiaction block.

```
notificationToken = [self.appState.currentProject addNotificationBlock:^(BOOL deleted, NSArray<RLMPropertyChange *> *changes, NSError *error) {
if (deleted) {
    NSLog(@"The object was deleted.");
} else if (error) {
    NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
} else {
    bool filterChanged = false;
    for (RLMPropertyChange * change in changes){
        if([change.name isEqualToString:@"filters"])
            filterChanged = true;
    }
    if(filterChanged){
        // compute predicate from filters
        // predicate = [NSPredicate ...
        styles = [Style objectsWithPredicate:predicate]
        notificationTokenStyles = [styles addNotificationBlock:^(RLMResults<Style *> * _Nullable results, RLMCollectionChange * _Nullable change, NSError * _Nullable error) {
            // react on changed styles.
        }]; // <- RLMException here
    }
}];
}
}];
```

I know that this is technically not possible, but for me it is necessary. Can I somehow dispatch or defer the nested addNotificationBlock to another thread or so? I know I could wait 500 ms, but that would result in a race condition.

Now, my problem is that as soon as I perform a wirte transaction that leads to the first notification block to execute, I encounter `RLMException: Cannot register notification blocks from within write transactions.` just at the nested addNotificationBlock.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. What problem are you running into with adding the notification block from within the notification?

Comment: I am facing `RLMException: Cannot register notification blocks from within write transactions.` It seems that the nested addnotifactionblock fires already doring the write transaction that leads to the first notification block to be executed. - Edited original question.

Comment: A write transaction is implicitly started in the notification block. Therefore, you can not register a notification from the notification block. What we want to ask is the reason to register in the notification block. It does not seem to matter if you register outside the block.

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: well, no clean solution. I found a non-elegant and dirty workaround: use `dispatch_after` to postpone the inner addNotificationBlock to another thread, however this obviously results in a race condition. I changed my whole program logic in such a way that the inner notification block is not necessary anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known problem (see [this Realm issue on GitHub](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4818)).

You can either wrap the creation of the new `NotificationToken` like this (Swift code):

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // register observation blocks here
}
```

Or you can call `realm.refresh()` before starting the write transaction.